# PowerShell Winforms Textbox updates on other input but overwriteable

Tags: winforms, powershell

Afternoon all,

I wanna believe this one is pretty easy but hitting a wall and can't figure out why.
I have a PowerShell winform that's going to create a new user account from a template. One of the fields I'm working on now is the line manager; once a template account has been found, auto-fill the line manager field, but allow it to be overwritten if this is incorrect.

For the pre-populated stuff I've been using:

```
$FORMCONTROL.Add_TextChanged( {
```

However once the template has been found and the line manager field written too, I can't overwrite it. Is there another Event I should be using to populate the box but allow me to delete the content and add something else?

The code below is a much cut down version of what I'm using. The functions allow for finding a user account and populating the ReadOnly box.

```
Function FindUser {
  IF ( $SEARCHUSER -like $NULL -or $SEARCHUSER -like " *" )
     { } 
  ELSEIF ( $ACCOUNT = dsquery user -samid $SEARCHUSER )
     { $ACCOUNT     = Get-ADUser $SEARCHUSER -Property * }
  ELSEIF ( $ACCOUNT = Get-ADUser -Filter { mail -eq $SEARCHUSER } -ea sil )
     { $ACCOUNT     = Get-ADUser -Filter { mail -eq $SEARCHUSER } -Property * }
  ELSEIF ( dsquery user -name $SEARCHUSER )
     { $ACCOUNT     = Get-ADUser -Filter { name -eq $SEARCHUSER } -Property * }
  ELSE
     { $( foreach ( $SEARCHUSER in ( Get-ADUser -Filter { ( Surname -like $SEARCHUSER ) -and ( Enabled -eq $TRUE ) 
                    } -Properties Mail, Department, Office | sort Name ) )
                  { $SEARCHUSER | Select Name, @{ N = "Username" ; E = { $_.SamAccountName } }, Mail, Department, Office
                  } ) | Out-GridView -Title 'Select the user account' -OutputMode Single | %{
          TRY
              { $ACCOUNT = Get-ADUser $_.UserName -Property * }
          CATCH
              { } } }

  IF ( ( $ACCOUNT.SamAccountName ).count -eq 1 )
     { $Script:ACCOUNT = $ACCOUNT }
  ELSE
     { $Script:ACCOUNT = $NULL } }


Function TemplateUser {
  IF ( $ACCOUNT -ne $NULL )
     { $TAB1TEMPLATE_5.Text = ( $ACCOUNT.Name ) }

  ELSEIF ( $TAB1TEMPLATE_3.Text.Length -lt 4 )
     { $TAB1TEMPLATE_5.Text = $NULL  } }


# Creates the parent form and controls
$SDC                       = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$SDC.Location              = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 270,175 )
$SDC.Size                  = New-Object System.Drawing.Size( 900,600 )
$SDC.StartPosition         = "CenterScreen"
$SDC.BackColor             = "Lavender"
$SDC.Font                  = "Calibri, 8.5"
$SDC.FormBorderStyle       = "Fixed3D"


#Tab 1 Template Account Label
$TAB1TEMPLATE_2            = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TAB1TEMPLATE_2.Location   = '35,90'
$TAB1TEMPLATE_2.Size       = '200,20'
$TAB1TEMPLATE_2.Font       = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Calibri",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold ) 
$TAB1TEMPLATE_2.Text       = "Who are we using as a template?"
$SDC.Controls.Add( $TAB1TEMPLATE_2 )

#Tab 1 Template Textbox
$TAB1TEMPLATE_3            = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TAB1TEMPLATE_3.Location   = '20,115'
$TAB1TEMPLATE_3.Size       = '200,20'
$TAB1TEMPLATE_3.Font       = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Calibri",9 )
$SDC.Controls.Add( $TAB1TEMPLATE_3 )

#Tab 1 Template Textbox - When hit Return
$TAB1TEMPLATE_3.Add_KeyDown( { 
    IF ( $_.KeyCode -eq 'Enter' )
       { $SEARCHUSER = $TAB1TEMPLATE_3.Text ; FindUser ; TemplateUser } } )

#Tab 1 Template Account's Full Name
$TAB1TEMPLATE_5            = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TAB1TEMPLATE_5.Location   = '20,150'
$TAB1TEMPLATE_5.Size       = '200,20'
$TAB1TEMPLATE_5.ReadOnly   = $TRUE
$TAB1TEMPLATE_5.Font       = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Calibri",9 )
$SDC.Controls.Add( $TAB1TEMPLATE_5 )



#Tab 1 Line Manager Label
$TAB1MANAGER_2             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$TAB1MANAGER_2.Location    = '35,400'
$TAB1MANAGER_2.Name        = "Manager"
$TAB1MANAGER_2.Size        = '245,20'
$TAB1MANAGER_2.Font        = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Calibri",10,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold ) 
$TAB1MANAGER_2.Text        = "Line Manager"
$SDC.Controls.Add( $TAB1MANAGER_2 )

#Tab 1 Line Manager Textbox
$TAB1MANAGER_3             = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TAB1MANAGER_3.Location    = '20,420'
$TAB1MANAGER_3.Size        = '245,20'
$TAB1MANAGER_3.Name        = "Manager"
$TAB1MANAGER_3.Font        = New-Object System.Drawing.Font( "Calibri",9 ) 
$SDC.Controls.Add( $TAB1MANAGER_3 )
$TAB1MANAGER_3.Text        = $( If ( $TAB1TEMPLATE_3.text -eq $NULL ) { "hi" } )

$SDC.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: What do you mean by you 'can't overwrite it'?

Comment: Just edit the `TextBox.Text` field.  Also, stop formatting your code like 1950s COBOL; your coworkers will thank you.

Comment: Also what does the .TextChanged code look like t=for that control?

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have fixed it by editing the Function TemplateUser:

```
Function TemplateUser {
  IF ( $ACCOUNT -ne $NULL )
     { $TAB1TEMPLATE_5.Text = ( $ACCOUNT.Name )
       $TAB1MANAGER_3.Text  = ( Get-ADUser $ACCOUNT.Manager ).Name
        }

  ELSEIF ( $TAB1TEMPLATE_3.Text.Length -lt 4 )
     { $TAB1TEMPLATE_5.Text = $NULL  } }
```

Lord knows what I was doing wrong in the first place as didn't save the changes.

@TheIncorrigible1 - Curious to know what you mean by the formatting. Genuinely. Is there a more efficient way of writing? I'm aware that when complete this script is going to be pretty big so if I'm using unnecessary code I'm all ears.

Comment: Formatting refers to the style of your code. There are a few style guides out there but they are all pretty close to the same. One is here: https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle